# how to make multiple views in viewController with storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard

It might be silly but i am new to iOS development.

Because i have to handle situation where i need to manage multiple views and display anyone at a time. 
Doing everything in code takes too much time but visually it takes less and i can design as per my needs.

I was adding multiple views to my viewcontroller in storyboard by mistake i drag and drop one of my views on at bottom panel of view controller as shown in below pic.

So is this another way we can handle multiple view ?
What's its purpose ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's just creates another top level view which will not show on screen. In theory you could populate this second top level view and then swap it out with the current main view as required in code and IBOutlets.

Comment: can you give a sample code in reference to your answer

Answer (score 0):

You will be in better control if you make multiple ViewController. 
Doing so will make good use of MVC pattern and you can easily add multiple view in each view controller. It will lead to separation of concern as well.

```
Parent ViewController
|
|--> Child ViewController
     |
     |--> Sub Views
```

To add ViewController As child view controller just do this -

```
    CGFloat ht = self.view0.frame.size.height;
    VC *vc1     = [[VC alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:vc1];

    CGRect frame            = self.view.bounds;
    frame.origin.y          = ht;
    frame.size.height       -= ht;
    vc1.view.frame          = frame;
    [self.view addSubview:vc1.view];

    [vc1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Doing so will ease making good MVC pattern so that each view controller has its talk with different models and only let sub-views draw there views.